# Write SQL Statements to File

Tags: java, jooq

I use jOOQs UpdatableRecord and call `updatableRecord.store()` to execute the Insert or Update statements.

Now I want to save the SQL statements that are executed to a file because I need to execute these statements on another database as well.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: My use case is something completely different. I want to record what the user is doing in the UI and then replay this on an other database instance. No need to downvote!

Comment: Oh I didn't downvote, I don't think I've ever even done that on a question. But yeah you're right, my advice _is_ irrelevant in that use case. I've been on SO too long in one sitting when the questions start to meld. Have a free upvote from the negatives

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Unfortunately I cannot see who is down voting.But thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) or use the built in `LoggerListener` (which adds some extra log content), see here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging.

Your own `ExecuteListener` could look like this:

```
public class Logger extends DefaultExecuteListener {
    @Override
    public void executeStart(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        MyUtils.writeToFile(ctx.sql());
    }
}
```

The listener is then added to your [`Configuration`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Configuration.html#derive-org.jooq.ExecuteListener...-)

Comment: The provided logger is clearly the way to go. You can already customize the output sufficiently; there is no need to introduce an additional listener to do the same thing.

Comment: I only need this in one place in the application. So I want to get a particular statement from a store() call. Is this also possible?

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Btw. you have typo in the documentation. The class is TestStatisticsListener but you are configurin: configuration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new StatisticsListener()));

Comment: @Michael: The `LoggerListener` has a lot of side effects, including printing the bind values in debug level, as well as the result sets and other information that might not be useful to the OP. I don't think it is such a "clearly" better approach.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Thanks, will fix immediately: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9024. From most to least hacky: You can of course use a regular expression on the SQL statement to filter them, you could filter the stack trace to look for `store()` calls, you could add a `RecordListener` that puts some variable in some scope (e.g. `ThreadLocal`, or your `Configuration`) to indicate that you're in a specific `store()` call, or you could have two separate `Configuration` objects for each task

Comment: @LukasEder It logs **separate** log entries with and without bind values. The result set is also a separate entry. Any of these can be easily ignored with a simple expression filter.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes

Comment: @LukasEder Ok I will filter for the updated table and only log that statements. Thanks for you help

Comment: @Michael: Sure, but 1) that's an equal amount of work as writing your own simple listener, 2) it depends on logging being turned on (e.g. `Settings.executeLogging`), which is per se a quite orthogonal concern, 3) it is not forward compatible, as there is absolutely no guarantee with respect to logging format (e.g. tomorrow, we might decide to always format log output, or truncate long queries). 4) It doesn't offer any way whatsoever of solving what Simon requested in the comments (i.e. filtering by query origin).

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Check [the existing logging implementation](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/tools/LoggerListener.java#L116)